# Is there a way to press a button on a hidden gui on a windows 10 service?

Tags: windows, user-interface, service

When I run my batch file from a DOS prompt, it takes about 10 seconds to complete.
When I run that batch file (indirectly) from a Windows service, it hangs and I believe one of the applications it starts is trying to display a 'nag' dialog (I can see the offending application in Task Manager) and it never completes.

Is there a way to send a button-press to the hidden UI ?

The OS is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.
I have tried using SysInternals ProcessExplorer's 'Bring To Front' button but it is says there is no UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution to the question but this resolved my issue and may provide a clue to others with a similar issue: 
The service that calls the batch file was running with a Working Directory of C:\Windows\System. I changed the working directory to the batch file's directory (to replicate the environment of running the batch file from DOS) and now the application doesn't hang.